# Скрипт для развертывания проекта docker4wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bash, docker, docker-compose, .bashrc

Я пишу свой собственный сценарий bash, который загрузит последнюю версию docker4wordpress, а также развернет проект (создаст пользователя, удалит ненужные плагины, темы).

```
get_latest_release() {
  curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$1/releases/latest" | grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*?(?=")'
}

createwp()
{
  wp_tar=$(get_latest_release wodby/docker4wordpress)
  git clone --depth 1 --branch $wp_tar https://github.com/wodby/docker4wordpress.git
  cd docker4wordpress/
  rm -rf .git/
  docker-compose up -d
  docker container exec my_wordpress_project_php wp core install \
                                                       --url=http://wp.docker.localhost:8000 \
                                                       --title=TEST \
                                                       --admin_user=Vitalik \
                                                       --admin_password=111 \
                                                       --admin_email='example@gmail.com'
  docker container exec my_wordpress_project_php wp plugin uninstall hello akismet 
  docker container exec my_wordpress_project_php wp theme delete twentynineteen twentytwenty
  docker container exec my_wordpress_project_php wp user update 1 --show_admin_bar_front=false --admin_color=midnight
  echo "Your site run in http://wp.docker.localhost:8000"
}
```

После создания всех контейнеров я получу следующую ошибку

*Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at mariadb. This could mean your host’s database server is down. Error: Error establishing a database connection.*

Насколько я понимаю, команды wp cli выполняются, когда контейнер базы данных еще не создан.

Я попытался получить идентификатор процесса docker-compose и дождаться его завершения, но это не сработало.

```
docker-compose up -d
pid=$!
wait $pid
docker ...
```

Answer (score 0):

В этой сборке надо указывать все данные в файле .env https://github.com/wodby/docker4wordpress/blob/master/.env

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/579502)

Comment: @0xdb но это не ответ на вопрос, проблема явно не в файле .env и доступам в нем. Допустим если я обрежу скрипт до docker-compose up -d подожду пока поднимутся все контейнеры, я с легкостью могу выполнить все дальнейшие  команды в терминале.